# Foursquare Check-In via Native App without Account

Tags: android, iphone, geolocation, foursquare

I have many business locations for which I am building a single native app for Android and a single native app for iPhone.

I would like people to be able to check-in to my establishment whilst inside my app. I don't want users to have to create a Foursquare account, I simply want to use Foursquare's ability to check-in rather than reinventing the wheel and creating all of the check-in geolocation logic.

Keep in mind that I want to keep track of how many times an individual has checked-in to a specific location.

Any suggestions for a solution or direction?

Comment: I don't think there is a solution. Foursquare will almost certainly require an account to have someone checkin (the account is how it stores all of the data on the backend). The closest you could get is embed the credentials for a single account into your app. But then everyone who checks in anywhere is going to be checked in under your account, and there will be no info linking them to the "check in" this may also be against their ToS.

Comment: OK, is the only solution to create my own geolocation process? One where I determine their location within certain accuracy?

Comment: This is not a question of geolocation. It is perfectly fine to query nearby venues from the Foursquare API without account. It is the process of actually checking in to a venue that requires users to have an account. You could make your own checkin system based on foursquare venues of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the point of checking-in is to use it as a kind of advertisement that people broadcast to all of their friends. In that case you definitely want them to be using their own accounts.

Otherwise who is checking in? John Doe? What's the point of that?

If you're worried that not enough of your customers use Foursquare, perhaps Facebook is a viable alternative?